# Can't play GTA V online when I could yesterday

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I was playing online yesterday with my friends at my moms house and when I come to my dads it won't let me play. I have an XBox 360 and both houses and I have Xbox live. I don't have gold and it let me play but now it says I don't have the right permissions.

Comment: If it is a different account it may have different permissions. One of them may have parental permissions set so certain games/features are not accessible

Comment: I have everything accessible and it still won't let me play..

Answer (score 4):

> I don't have gold and it let me play but now it says I don't have the right permissions.

You need Xbox Live Gold to play GTA Online

> Like OM3GA said, you can play single player free of a multiplayer fee - But with Xbox Live you are required to have a gold membership (Paid Membership) to access the majority of Xbox Lives features - Including, but not limited to;
>
> Online Multiplayer, Netflix and a plethora of other applications.
>
> One perk though is the added security, at the moment everything is a little hectic but most of the hacking in the past has occurred on the PlayStation System as Microsoft isn't anywhere near a lenient as Sony when it comes to hacking on their servers.

Source: [Rockstar Support - "Do you need xbox live gold to play grand theft auto online on xbox 360"](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/201663553-Do-you-need-xbox-live-gold-to-play-grand-theft-auto-online-on-xbox-360)

Since you don't have Xbox Live Gold you've been using your friend's Xbox Live Gold accounts, since they would have set the 360 as their home system.

First you need to check if your father has an Xbox Live Gold account and that it's valid (it's a paid subscription so he may have cancelled it if he had it before). You also need to check that he hasn't blocked you from accessing Xbox Live Gold from his account

> The Xbox 360 console lets you customize and manage your family's access to games, movies, and television content. The Xbox 360 parental controls can be used to control both the console itself and access to content on Xbox Live, including:
>
> - Which games can be played.
> - Which movies and TV shows can be watched.
> - How long each family member can use the console on a daily or weekly basis.
> - **Whether or not a family member can access Xbox Live.**

Source: [Xbox Support - Set parental controls for Xbox 360](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/security/xbox-live-parental-control)

Ultimately, since you don't have Xbox Live Gold you are reliant on others to have it so you should be checking with them if they are able to access Xbox Live Gold first. If they can't access it, neither can you.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be that you played while Sony and Microsoft had their campaign letting everyone [play online for free](http://www.polygon.com/2017/2/16/14637048/ps4-psn-xbox-live-free-multiplayer)?

- Microsoft let everyone play for free between February 16<sup>th</sup> to February 19<sup>th</sup>
- Sony let everyone play for free between February 17<sup>th</sup> to February 23<sup>rd</sup>

Comment: This would make so much sense since the asker stated that they don't have gold (I was baffled by how they were able to play online at all then).  I didn't even know this event was going on.  I think when the question was asked, the event was still happening, so this is possible.